# Unique random numbers

Tags: c, random

I have been working on a random number gen, that creates 6 unique random numbers 1-49, i can get it working so theres 6 random numbers 1-49, or 6 unique random numbers but not all of the above at the same time. I can get the code to compile but it just crashes everytime i try and use the `% 49 +1` in different spots.

Code i am using is:

```
{
                int numbers [SIZE];
                int i, j, n;

                srand (time(NULL));

                for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
                    numbers[i] = i;

                for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
                {
                j = rand() % 49 + 1;
                n = numbers[j];
                numbers[j] = numbers[i];
                numbers[i] = n;
                }

                for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
                MyOutputDebugString ("%d\n", numbers[i]);
```

SIZE is defined as 6.

Thanks

Comment: any crash log? what kind of crash?

Comment: if rand() returns 0 j evaluates to 50. numbers[] is just SIZE long so...

Answer (score 5):

> SIZE is defined as 6.

So, your array `numbers` is like

```
int numbers [6];
```

Once

```
j = rand() % 49 + 1;
```

is executed, `j` will be between in [ 1; 49 ], so, if it's > 5, on this line, you'll have an out of range index::

```
n = numbers[j];
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is comming from calling a portion of the array that does not exist.

```
n = numbers[j];
```

The value for j is going to be your random number and most likly larger then your SIZE.

Change this part of your code:

```
                for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)                           
                    numbers[i] = i;

                for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
                   {                       
                   j = rand() % 49 + 1; 
                   n = numbers[j];  
                   numbers[j] = numbers[i];
                   numbers[i] = n;
                   }
```

You can manage to pull off the same effect in one loop like this:

```
for (i = 0; 1 < SIZE; i++)
{
   numbers[i] = rand() % 49 + 1;
}
```

I hope this helps.